# Change Anchor ID When Media Query Active

Tags: jquery, html, media-queries

I'm trying to change the id of an anchor tag when my media query kicks in. This is the code I'm currently trying but failing with:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($('.container').css('width') == "100%"){
        $("a[href='#Why-Us']").attr("href='#Why-Us-2'");
    }
});
```

I basically want to replace `href="#Why-Us"` with `href="Why-Us-2"`

Thanks.

Edit ** The code I have for the smooth scroll

```
$("a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

// prevent default anchor click behavior
target = this.hash;
e.preventDefault();

// animate
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
 }, 500, function(){

   // when done, add hash to url
   // (default click behaviour)
   window.location.hash = target;
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.scroll-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},800);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: max-width 580px for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the test works as you expect but the change of attribute should be

```
$("a[href='#Why-Us']").attr("href","#Why-Us-2");
```

---

for handling media query changes through javascript see http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:580px)", {
    match : function() {
        $("a[href='#Why-Us']").attr("href","#Why-Us-2");
    },      

    // OPTIONAL
    // If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions 
    // *from a matched state to an unmatched state*.
    unmatch : function() {
        $("a[href='#Why-Us-2']").attr("href","#Why-Us");
    }

});
```

Demo using the above plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/nr2xhzja/

Comment: That's not taking effect :(

Comment: @Matt added full example

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, I check in firebug and the id doesn't change. I also tested on my phone and the link doesn't resolve.

Comment: Why use this enquire thing when you could simply use $(window).width() ... ?

Comment: you want to change the id ? or the `href` attribute ?

Comment: The id. It's a single scrolling page and I want to have the link resolve to a different section on the smaller screens.

Comment: @matt you seem to be confusing some terminology. If you want a link to point to another element you need to change the `href` attribute of that link. If there are other scripts that handle the links, they might be doing some initialization work before we alter the href. You will need to post a working example so we know what might conflict with our code..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clued up with jQuery or JS. I assumed that was what I was showing in the code I had

Comment: @matt see this updated fiddle that shows that it should work http://jsfiddle.net/nr2xhzja/1/ (*unless other scripts on your site interfere*)

Comment: @cport1 because it can handle both match and unmatch (*when resizing browser*) and can work for as many media-queries you want and with anything supported by media queries..

Comment: It still doesn't seem to update, would it help if I upload the files to my server so you can view the site/code?

Comment: yes that would help. also see this demo which incorporates your scrolling code: http://jsfiddle.net/nr2xhzja/2/

Comment: I tried adding the new code that includes mine but then to smooth scroll didn't work at all. I've uploaded the files anyway http://www.mmwebco.co.uk

Comment: @matt the code at the end does not work because the validate plugin is not included and it causes an error (*the code following the error line is not run*). You also need to include the enquire plugin in order for my code to run

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thanks for the update and sorry for the late response. Would you mind showing me how I would do this? As I said, I'm not too clued up with jQuery and JS so I have no clue how to do what you are saying

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I was having a stupid moment lol. The code now works perfect, you are a genius, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You're using .attr wrong.  It should be something like ::

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($( window ).width() <= 580) {
        $("a[href='#Why-Us']").attr("href", "#Why-Us-2");
        console.log('window smaller than 580px');
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/byzm2bok/

Comment: That's not making it change either

Comment: added a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: oh, I missed the '#' on my #Why-Us-2 ... updated my answer .. it does work